# Can't determine the principal used to LDAP syncrepl GSSAPI

Tags: ldap, openldap, kerberos, sasl, gssapi

I've configured two openldap fully functional in HA (syncrepl mode provider - slave).
After testing that simple bind syncrepl works flawlessly, I'm trying to deploy from scratch using only GSSAPI to avoid the use of plain text passwords.
I've configured the client (ldap.conf) to use GSSAPI and works great, so it should work too for syncrepl.
I've configured the provider and the consumer.

This is the configuration of the olcSyncrepl under the hdb database. Omitting the authcid and authzid does not change the final result:

```
    olcSyncrepl{0}: rid=001 
    provider="ldap://authsrv1.ex.ample.com" 
    bindmethod=sasl 
    saslmech=gssapi 
    searchbase="dc=ex,dc=ample,dc=com" 
    type=refreshAndPersist 
    retry="30 5 300 3" 
    interval=00:00:01:00
```

If the configuration is modified to simple bind, it replicates flawlessly. The krb5.keytab has been added to the sysconfig openldap file.

I would be able to solve it if I could be able to know what principal is using to attempt the replication, but logs are not showing that information (LogLevel 255).

```
> slapd[2091]: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may
> provide more information (No Kerberos credentials available)
> 
> slapd[2091]: slap_client_connect: URI=ldap://authsrv1.ex.ample.com
> ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s failed (-2)
```

ldapwhoami using GSSAPI works flawlessly after using kinit.

EDIT:
This is my config of /etc/sasl2/slapd.conf

```
mech_list: gssapi diges-md5 cram-md5 external
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
keytab: /etc/ldap.keytab
```

ldap.keytab contains the ldap/authsrv1.ex.ample.com and ldap/authsrv2.ex.ample.com principals keys and its owned by user ldap and group ldap. Also I created a syncrepl inetOrgPerson and added a {SASL} mechanism as password to check If I could use a dedicated account instead of ldap/authsrv...

If I perform a kinit from both of the servers:

```
kinit -k -t /etc/ldap.keytab syncrepl
kinit -k -t /etc/ldap.keytab ldap/authsrv1.ex.ample.com
kinit -k -t /etc/ldap.keytab ldap/authsrv2.ex.ample.com
```

The KDC gives me a ticket and then, I can perform a ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI or ldapwhoami -Y GSSAPI flawlessly.

Also the ldap.conf client is configured to use GSSAPI and works flawlessly too in all our clients.

```
BASE dc=ex,dc=ample,dc=com
URI ldap://authsrv1.ex.ample.com:389/,ldap://authsrv2.ex,ample.com:389/
TLS_CACERT /certs/EXAMPLE.pem
TLS_CACERTDIR /certs/
TLS_CERT /certs/authsrv1.ex.ample.com.pem
TLS_KEY /certs/authsrv1.ex.ample.com.key.pem
SUDOERS_BASE ou=SUDOers,dc=ex,dc=ample,dc=com
SASL_MECH GSSAPI
SASL_REALM EX.AMPLE.COM
GSSAPI_SIGN on
GSSAPI_ENCRYPT off
NETWORK_TIMEOUT 10
BIND_POLICY soft
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers root,ldap,named,avahi,haldaemon,dbus
bind_timeout 2
nss_reconnect_tries 2
nss_reconnect_sleeptime 1
nss_reconnect_maxconntries 3
```

Our webserver allows the authentication using SASLAUTHD and works flawlessly too.
All we can't configure is syncrepl via GSSAPI.

I've tried also specifying authcid and authzid and I've the following authregex in the provider cn=config:

```
olcAuthRegexp: {0}uid=(.*),cn=gssapi,cn=auth ldap://dc=ex,dc=ample,dc=com??sub?(&(uid=$1)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)
```

About the ACL, I've tried to replicate with the same user (syncrepl) with simple authentication mechanism and it works great.

Any Ideas?

Thank you so much.

Best Regards.

Comment: you should have somewhere a keytab for the gssapi replication (where? who knows, you show no configuration); using klist -k -t /path/to/keytab you should see the kerberos principal info in that keytab, which should be an account with sufficient privileges to replicate the ldap database. Again, this is all theory, because we can see nothing concrete here.

Comment: Hello Natxo Asenjo, I added some configurations to the main post. I hope you can help us now. Thank you so much. Regards

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of days, weeks... trying to figure out what was going on...

The issue was in /etc/sysconfig/openldap. Changing:

```
OPENLDAP_USER="ldap"
OPENLDAP_GROUP="ldap"
```

To:

```
OPENLDAP_USER=""
OPENLDAP_GROUP=""
```

Solved the issue.

Comment: I fear you may now be unnecessarily running your slapd as root.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
$
$
$ grep KRB5 /etc/sysconfig/slapd
KRB5_KTNAME="FILE:/etc/openldap/ldap.keytab"
KRB5_CLIENT_KTNAME="FILE:/etc/openldap/ldap.keytab"
$ ls -l /etc/openldap/ldap.keytab
-rw-------. 1 ldap ldap 346 Jun 15  2015 /etc/openldap/ldap.keytab
$
$
$  ps aux | grep slapd | grep -v grep
ldap      1121  1.2  3.9 356408 39748 ?        Ssl  22:07   0:02 /usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h ldapi:/// ldap:/// ldaps:///
```

Comment: Hey, @84104 thank you for your comment. You have any idea why replication does not work if the service is not started with root user?

Comment: Can the non-root user read the keytab?

Comment: yes, is the owner.

Comment: More than just ownership can go into reading a file. AppArmor? SELinux?

Comment: Selinux is disabled and AppArmor is disabled and masked.